# Why pending items and/or pending changes inside our custom list is being excluded/ignored from search

Tags: 2013, development, search, search-results, content-search-web-part

I have a custom list inside our sharepoint 2013 on-premises enterprise farm. now i set the following versioning settings inside our cusotm list:-

[image]

When someone creates a new item inside the list, its status will be pending.And i can see everything since i am the site admin, but inside the search results, the item will not be shown unless it get approved. Also if the item is modified and its status got changed from Approved to Pending, then only the approved changes will be shown insde the search. when i talk about search i am referring to these locations:-

1. List level search. search box inside the list view.
2. site level search . search box at the site home page.
3. content search web part.

So can anyone advice on this issue.. as i know search will show the data based on user permissions. so if the user can view a pending item and/or a pending changes ,, then why those pending items/changes will not be shown for him inside the search functionalities, unless the item is approved??. this is causing  conflict results for the same user, when he view an item inside the Content Search web-part and when he view the same item inside the list view or inside the list display form ??
Thanks

Comment: Search indexes only major versions, as you have found out

Comment: @RobertLindgren and can we modify the search service  to search minor versions as well?

Comment: You can flip the radio button in your screen shot to "any user who can read items". But that mean that all users with read or higher permissions will be able to see your drafts (unpublished) versions

Comment: @RobertLindgren But i do not want to show pending items to all users.. so do you mean that the "Draft Item Security" options control if the pending item should be shown inside the search?? any this applies to admin user and users with Approve permission ?

Comment: No, what you are trying to do is not possible with search. Search index only one version of each file, then decides if you should see it or not with ACL:s